# Creating a new column consisting of lists in a DataFrame using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

Given the following `DataFrame`:

```
   t
0  3
1  5
```

I would like to create a new column where wach entry is a list which is a function of the row it is in. In particular it should have a list with all positive integers which not greater than the entry in column `t`. So the output should be:

```
   t  newCol
0  3  [1,2,3]
1  5  [1,2,3,4,5]
```

In other words, I want to apply `list(range(1,t+1))` to each row. I know how to do it in a loop, but have a long `DataFrame`, so I am looking for speed. Thank you.

Comment: `df['newCol'] = df.t.map(np.arange) + 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach using `NumPy` methods -

```
a = df.t.values
idx = a.cumsum()
id_arr = np.ones(idx[-1],dtype=int)
id_arr[idx[:-1]] = -a[:-1]+1
df['newCol'] = np.split(id_arr.cumsum(),idx[:-1])
```

Sample run -

```
In [76]: df
Out[76]: 
   t                 newCol
0  4           [1, 2, 3, 4]
1  3              [1, 2, 3]
2  7  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
3  2                 [1, 2]
4  5        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
5  3              [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

this is so very close to @Divakar's answer but I believe a tad bit more intuitive.

***get values for quicker numpy access***
`v = df.t.values`
`[3 5]`
***get cumulative sums of `v`***
`cumsum = v.cumsum()`
`[3 8]`
***get some differences***
used to track splits and take differences later
`diffs = cumsum - v`
`[0 3]`
***compile a big cumulative sum***
This is the starting point for the final values
`prevals = np.ones(cumsum[-1], dtype=int).cumsum()`
`[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]`
***finally, split and put***
`df['new_col'] = np.split(prevals - np.repeat(diffs, v), diffs[1:])`
[image]

---

***all together***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(t=[4, 3, 7, 2, 5, 3]))
v = df.t.values
cumsum = v.cumsum()
diffs = cumsum - v
prevals = np.ones(cumsum[-1], dtype=int).cumsum()
df['new_col'] = np.split(prevals - np.repeat(diffs, v), diffs[1:])
```